# How do I template overload an operator for a group of related classes without conflicting with standard library operators?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++03

This seems like a fairly straight forward idea: I have a group of classes for which I should be able to write an operator, let's say subtraction, using basically the exact same code.

When trying to do this the "obvious" way, i.e:

```
template <typename T>
T operator-(T a, const T& b) {
    return a -= b;
}
```

Then, on certain compilers, this seems to conflict with a subtraction operator for iterators (specifically it breaks on gcc 3.4.6 and Apple LLVM, while seemingly working fine on gcc version 4 or newer), and I get the following error:

```
 error: use of overloaded operator '-' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<const double *>' and 'const_iterator'
      (aka '__wrap_iter<const_pointer>'))
```

I also considered template overloading for just a base class from which all of the classes in the group would be derived from, but then since the first parameter is passed by value, I think information specific to the subclass would be lost during the copy.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to do this that keeps all these compilers happy?

Edit: the solution should ideally work in C++03.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a base class, adl koenig operators, and sfinae.

```
namespace ops{
  struct subtract_support{
    template<class T,
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<subtract_support, T>{}, int> =0
    >
    friend T operator-( T lhs, T const& rhs ){
      lhs-=rhs;
      return lhs;
    }
  };
}
```

Now inheriting from `ops::subtract_support` causes `-` to work for your type.  (Note the two-line body: that ensures the lhs is moved out of `-`, unlike your version in the OP).

Merely namespace restricting results in your `-` being found any template produced type where one of tge arguments comes from your namespace, and other unintended cases: adl operates on types whose template members come from a specific namespace.<sup>1</sup>

This trick lets you mark each type as using this technique at the point of declaration.

There are almost zero binary layout implications of this technique.  But if you need something obscure like layout compatibility of prefixes a traits class may be required instead.

---

Now, this is a C++11 solution.  Apparently the OP needs C++03.  Well, the best way forward is to implement it as much like C++11 so code can be deleted when you upgrade your compiler.

`enable_if` can easily be written in C++03.  `is_base_of` takes a few more lines:

```
namespace notstd{
  namespace details{
    template<class T, class U>
    struct base_test{
      typedef char no; // sizeof(1)
      struct yes { no unused[2]; }; // sizeof(2) or greater
      static yes test(T*); // overload if arg is convertible-to-T*
      static no test(...); // only picked if first overload fails
      // pass a `U*` to `test`.  If the result is `yes`, T
      // is a base of U.  Note that inaccessible bases might fail here(?)
      // but we are notstd, good enough.
      enum {value= (
        sizeof(yes)==sizeof(test((U*)0))
      )};
    };
  }
  template<class Base, class T>
  struct is_base_of{
    enum{value=details::base_test<Base,T>::value};
  };
  template<bool b, class T=void>
  struct enable_if {};
  template<class T>
  struct enable_if<true, T> {
    typedef T type;
  };
}
```

We also need to tweak the SFINAE in the template ADL operator for C++03 compliance:

```
namespace ops{
  struct subtract_support{
    template<class T>
    friend
    typename notstd::enable_if<notstd::is_base_of<subtract_support, T>::value, T>::type
    operator-( T lhs, T const& rhs ){
      lhs-=rhs;
      return lhs;
    }
  };
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d86a4b0d6f699ae).

---

<sup>1</sup> As an example, if `Foo` is a type in the namespace with a greedy `-` template operator, then `decltype(v0-v1)` where `v0` and `v1` are `vector<Foo>` will be `vector<Foo>`.  That is a false positive (it will not compile).  But a `vec3<Foo>` (vector space of 3 Foo) with its own `-` would result in the same ambiguity.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have mentioned it needs to work with C++03.

Comment: Fascinating note, if I may say so. I'm favoring this question to keep track of this answer.

Comment: How would you go about constraining it for types that can't inherit? (I'm mainly thinking about `enum`s)

Comment: @story traits classes, or (my preference) a adl-lookup traits function.  So `constexpr std::true_type supports_x(tag_t<some_enum>){return {};}`, possibly defined by macro (ik), used to sfinae guard the operator.  Enums that want to enable the feature can declare their support.  Less than perfect, because still need to get the operator in scope to use it, unlike the inheritance/namespace trick which drags it in.

Comment: @ChrisUsher C++03 support added

Answer (score 3):

Put this template and your custom data structures in same namespace (if they are in root namespace - just move them).

Because of [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), compiler will look for this operator in namespace of your structures, and find it without problems and ambiguity.

Comment: By far the cleanest solution

Comment: Not good enough: try `v0-v1` where they are vectors over the types in question.

Comment: @Yakk, that would result in an error. Which i'd expect since vectors don't support this operation at all. So you haven't exactly made your point.

Comment: @story Any template produced type that supports `-` that takes `T` as a template argument will find this greedy `-` and generate spurious errors.  If it does not support `-`, sfinae tests will think it does: `decltype(v0-v1)` is a `std::vector<T>`!  Never define greedy templates like this unless the lookup triggering "token" is obscurel `-` does not qualify.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) may have helped you. Given you have a base class `Base`:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>>
T operator-(T a, const T& b) {
        return a -= b;
}
```

Here your operator will only be considered for types `T` derived from `Base`.

**EDIT:**

The linked pages of cppreference.com show possible implementations, so you can use them in C++03 as well by just implementing your own `enable_if` and `is_base_of`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have mentioned it needs to work with C++03.

Comment: The linked pages of cppreference.com show possible implementations, so you can use them in C++03 as well by just implementing your own `enable_if` and `is_base_of` ;)

Comment: @W.F. It does, rest assured

Comment: @StoryTeller does it? [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uM3wZSDr845qeJsQ)

Comment: @W.F. Fancy that, nicely caught. I wasn't remembering the restriction on function templates.

Answer (score 1):

Traversing [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764548/4324224) you could do it using simple sfinea with just one additional trait. c++03 compliant code:

```
namespace ops{
  struct subtract_support{
    template <class T>
    struct subtract_support_trait {
        typedef T type;
    };
    template<class T>
    friend typename T::template subtract_support_trait<T>::type operator-( T lhs, T const& rhs ){
      lhs-=rhs;
      return lhs;
    }
  };
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fIIo7X0T8YhdQ4B2)

Comment: Laugh, that is a bit funny.  Clever!  In C++11 if we non-publicly inherit from `subtract_support`, I think yours won't support `-`.  Would the `is_base_of` SFINAE?  Uncertain.

Comment: Oops you're right with inheritance... As I get back to computer I'll make an edit... Thanks!

Comment: @Yakk Wait... I'm not sure if `is_base_of` created as a simple trait can test non-public inheritance... Can it be even done for this use case in c++03? Need to think about it a bit more...