# How can I use std::is_base_of inside one of the hierarchy classes?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to do a program which is structurally similar to this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class A, class B, class C = void>
class Test {};

template <class A, class B>
class Test<A *, B *, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, B>::value>::type> {
public:
    int a;
};

class X {};

class Y : public X {
private:
    using T = Test<X *, Y *>;
    T t;
public:
    Y() : t() {t.a = 1;}
};
```

That is, I want to have a template instantiation inside a deriving class that uses both base and deriving classes, and that makes sure there is a deriving relationship between the two classes.

But this fails to compile under gcc 6.1.0. The error message is:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Y'
```

So what should I do to make this code work? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that it is explicitly stated that the second parameter of `std::is_base_of` must be complete type see e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)

Comment: But you could go along and implementing appropriate test yourself like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XtyrECZMSLVVywKl)... (I used here [Yakk's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40764548/4324224) from a different question/answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you specify a type as a non-pointer/non-reference object, it is required that you should have previously defined the (storage of) the type. If you use `T` as a pointer it should work as such:

```
class Y : public X {
private:
    using T = Test<X *, Y *>;
    T* t;
public:
    Y() : t(new T) {t->a = 1;}
};
```

This of course has a few disadvantages of its own.